# Titanium Studio 3.2.0 cannot debug using Genymotion 2.0.3

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, genymotion

I am using Titanium Studio 3.2.0 in MacOS X 10.9.1 for Android app development. I want to use Genymotion (2.0.3) Emulator for debugging. It works fine when the app "Run" but there is error when "debug". Here is the error message.

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.2.0, Titanium SDK version 3.2.0.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
[ERROR] :  The selected emulator "Nexus 7 - 4.3 - API 18 - 1280x800" does not have an SD card.
[ERROR] :  An SD card is required for debugging.
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

I tried to add the sdcard.vdi to the emulator but the emulator cannot recognize the SD card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was supposed to be resolved in Titanium SDK 3.2.0.GA with the pull request dated 12/5 (https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/commit/8e1f1c4a3734d5696383afca1c30765bac4f33b5) showing the changes.

However, the sdcard property isnt on the emu object at the time you try to debug.

Quick and dirty fix is to hack the sdk.

Line 1302 of {sdk}/android/cli/commands/_build.js has

`} else if (!emu.sdcard) {`

Replace that with:

`} else if (!emu.sdcard && (emu.type !== 'genymotion')) {`

and it should have you debugging.

[image]

(http://content.screencast.com/users/Stephen_Feather/folders/Jing/media/1063aa8a-0ae5-46e2-bc1a-3cf4c779dee6/00000344.png)

Comment: You shouldn't have to add the sdcard.vdi as most of the genymotion images already have /mnt/sdcard in them for compatibility.

My gut feeling is that in the move from the python build scripts to the new nodejs based scripts, some of the legacy emulator checks came along and have yet to be purged.